# Visual Basic simple/standard calculator continuous equal button bug

Tags: .net, vb.net

I'm creating a simple/standard calculator for my Minor A Exam in VB.net, but I'm having a bug where if I input 5+1 then it equals 6, but if I press the equals sign again, it does 5+6, not 6+1. I'm very new to coding so I don't know much, I'm suspecting I need to use a count, boolean or conditional statements but I don't know how or much about it.

i use tbDisplay to show what's inputed first, then tbDisplay2 for history purposes

```vb
Dim [operator] as String
Dim num1, num2 as Double

Private Sub btnPlus_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnPlus.Click
    [operator] = "+"
    num1 = tbDisplay.Text
    tbDisplay2.Text = CStr(num1) + " " + [operator]
    tbDisplay.Text = " "
End Sub


Private Sub btn_Result_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btn_Result.Click
    num2 = tbDisplay.Text

    If [operator] = "+" Then
        Result = num1 + num2
        tbDisplay.Text = Result
        tbDisplay2.Text = CStr(num1) + " " + [operator] + " " + CStr(num2) + " = " + CStr(Result)
    End If
```

Comment: An exam is meant to test what you've learned. Unfortunately, if you haven't learned enough to successfully complete the task, your grade should reflect this. However, here's some debugging advice. Get a pen/paper. Write down some sample input. Then read through your code just as the computer would and complete the computations. By doing this, you should be able to identify the issue.

Comment: On this paper track the values of `num1`, `num2`, `tbDisplay.Text` and `[operator]`. I.e., execute the code lines mentally one by one, as if they were executed by the computer.